# retorno nulo ao tentar persistir dados

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-ee

Estou com problemas sistema de cadastro e pesquisa ao persistir em método salvar da returno nulo, já mudei para @viewscoped meu bean mas nada, debuguei projeto e nada, não consigo identifica erro, estou iniciando em programação java web apanhado muito desde já agradeço.ao realizar debug deu campo de interrupção do campo CadastroProdutoService.serialVersionUID  coloquei como modificação mais não resolveu.

log erro:

> Inicialinado....
>   Hibernate: select categoria0_.id as id1_0_, categoria0_.categoria_pai_id as categori3_0_, categoria0_.descricao as descrica2_0_ from categoria categoria0_ where categoria0_.categoria_pai_id is null
>   Hibernate: select categoria0_.id as id1_0_0_, categoria0_.categoria_pai_id as categori3_0_0_, categoria0_.descricao as descrica2_0_0_, categoria1_.id as id1_0_1_, categoria1_.categoria_pai_id as categori3_0_1_, categoria1_.descricao as descrica2_0_1_ from categoria categoria0_ left outer join categoria categoria1_ on categoria0_.categoria_pai_id=categoria1_.id where categoria0_.id=?
>   subcategoria....
>   Hibernate: select categoria0_.id as id1_0_, categoria0_.categoria_pai_id as categori3_0_, categoria0_.descricao as descrica2_0_ from categoria categoria0_ where categoria0_.categoria_pai_id=?
>   Inicialinado....
>   jul 20, 2016 4:27:19 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
>   GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/produtos/CadastroProduto.xhtml]
>   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /produtos/CadastroProduto.xhtml @54,101 value="#{cadastroProdutoBean.produto.categoria}": Target Unreachable, 'produto' returned null
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findImplicitConverter(InputRenderer.java:160)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getOptionAsString(InputRenderer.java:146)
>       at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeOption(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:378)
>       at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeSelectItems(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:364)
>       at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeInput(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:146)
>       at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:93)
>       at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:67)
>   16:27:19.390 [http-bio-8080-exec-41] ERROR com.oliveira.pedidovenda.util.jsf.JsfExceptionHandler - Erro de sistema: /produtos/CadastroProduto.xhtml @54,101 value="#{cadastroProdutoBean.produto.categoria}": Target Unreachable, 'produto' returned null
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
>       at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:582)
>   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /produtos/CadastroProduto.xhtml @54,101 value="#{cadastroProdutoBean.produto.categoria}": Target Unreachable, 'produto' returned null
>       at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:100) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findImplicitConverter(InputRenderer.java:160) ~[primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
>       at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getOptionAsString(InputRenderer.java:146) ~[primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
>       at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeOption(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:378) ~[primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
>       at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeSelectItems(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:364) ~[primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
>       at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeInput(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:146) ~[primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
>       at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:93) ~[primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
>       at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403)
>       at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:67) ~[primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:582) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:403) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:322)
>       at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:322) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60)
>       at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
>       at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext.processPartial(OmniPartialViewContext.java:144)
>       at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PrimePartialViewContext.java:60) ~[primefaces-5.3.jar:5.3]
>       at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext.processPartial(OmniPartialViewContext.java:144) ~[omnifaces-2.4.jar:2.4]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:432) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:432)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:651)
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219) [javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:651) [javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat7-websocket.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 'produto' returned null
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:218) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:442) [catalina.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1082) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:623) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:148)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_92]
>       at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:82)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_92]
>       at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:171)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.70]
>       at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_92]
>   Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Target Unreachable, 'produto' returned null
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
>       ... 52 more

```
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:148) ~[jasper-el.jar:7.0.70]
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:82) ~[jasper-el.jar:7.0.70]
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:171) ~[jasper-el.jar:7.0.70]
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getType(WeldValueExpression.java:93) ~[weld-servlet-2.3.2.Final.jar:2.3.2.Final]
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98) ~[javax.faces-2.2.8-15.jar:2.2.8-15]
... 52 more
```

Listening for transport dt_shmem at address: tomcat_shared_memory_id

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi no log, o problema não está no momento da persistência, mas sim quando você acessa a página do cadastro do produto e ainda não há um produto selecionado, **#{cadastroProdutoBean.produto}** é nulo neste momento, e você tem um componente **selectOneMenu** apontando para **#{cadastroProdutoBean.produto.categoria}**.

Uma solução viável é exibir os componentes apenas quando #**{cadastroProdutoBean.produto}** não for nulo.

Uma ideia:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton action="#{cadastroProdutoBean.selecionarProduto}"
                     update="@form" />

    <h:panelGrid rendered="#{not empty cadastroProdutoBean.produto}">
        <!-- Componentes do form: categoria, etc -->
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Comment: olá Victor, não entendi necessariamente como seria!?